# sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'classes_' except that it actually does

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Python 3.10.10 is saying that 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'classes_' but the documentation at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html says that it DOES have attribute `'classes_'`.

I'm using a RandomForestClassifier in a RandomizedSearchCV in a make_pipeline.

```
param_dist = {"n_estimators": [100, 200],
              "max_depth": [3, None],
              "min_samples_split": [2, 7],
              "min_samples_leaf": [1, 3]
             }

def custom_scoring_function(y_true, y_pred):
    result = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
    return result 

score = make_scorer(custom_scoring_function, greater_is_better=True)

model = RandomForestClassifier()
model_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_dist, n_iter = 10, 
                              scoring = score, cv = 5, 
                              refit = True,
                              verbose = 3, random_state = 42)

pipeline = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), PCA(n_components="mle"), model_cv)
```

The pipeline runs just fine, but when I try to extract class labels like this
`class_labels = pipeline.classes_`

I get this result:

```
AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'classes_'
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(Estimator.)classes_` attribute is created lazily, during the `(Estimator.)fit(X, y)` method call.

Your estimator object has not been fitted. Therefore, its `classes_` attribute has not been created yet.

```py
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
assert not hasattr(clf, "classes_")
clf.fit(X, y)
assert hasattr(clf, "classes_")
```